# Angular and XAMPP CORS Policy

Tags: php, angular, xampp

I am trying to send some requests from my angular app to my local xampp server, but the requests are blocked due to CORS Policy.

I have already added following line to the httpd.conf file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

I have also added an .htaccess file to my htdocs folder with following content:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

I have also added this to my php file:`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` but this had no impact as well.

My angular app runs on `localhost:4200` and the xampp runs on `localhost:80`

I know allowing every origin is a great security issue, but it is only for testing purpose.

Comment: What happens if you send an OPTIONS request with postman?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a few more headers from your server side, namely [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) and [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers).

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");
```

Comment: I have added the following headers to my php file to which I send the requests, but this had also no impact, I get the same error as before. I call functions from other php scripts but i only need the headers in the php file I call from my angular app, right?

Comment: @DavidHuemer What do you see in response headers in network request?

Comment: In my network tab of chrome there are no response headers. The error message of the http request is:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/HG_EventsAPI/REST/api/Authentication.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: @DavidHuemer So these headers need to go when you send a response. Test with [`postman tool`](https://www.postman.com/) to see if you receive the headers.

Comment: With postman i get following headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.10
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10

Comment: Ok, it's difficult to debug this way.

Comment: Only Angular 8.3.21, in the backend i do not use any frameworks.

Comment: Ok, does this help https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techiediaries.com/amp/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your http.conf like this

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```